# How to calculate numbers in ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm trying to find a way to calculate numbers in a ListBox. Let's say I have few items in a ListBox: `3.15`, `2.45`, `2.84`, and more... every time I click a button new number comes up and goes to the ListBox and over there all numbers before plus the new one will sum up and will give me a result of all numbers. I'm working in C# WinForms.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Do you know how to create a listbox view and access or modify it's elements?

Comment: Add a button, create a click handler, and write code that iterates over the list and sums the numbers. Which part of that is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [ListBox.Items.Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.items?view=netcore-3.1), use it in the button's clicked event. Then go trough the Items with

```cs
foreach(var item in ListBox1.Items)
{
 //sum up all the items here
}
```

Then after it finishes display the result on a label.